# Variable in partial different than in parent template

Tags: pug

This is my code in `index.jade`:

```
- each question in questions
    - console.log('Question in index.jade: ', question);
    !=partial('question', question)
```

And this is my code in `question.jade`:

```
- console.log('Question in question.jade: ', question);
```

For some reason, both variables `question` are *different*. Am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `question` variable in an object with a key of `question` and pass that to the second parameter of the partial function. For example:

```
- each question in questions
  !=partial('question', { question: question })
```

Then the partial view will have access to the question variable you want. Also, assuming you are using jade with express and the partial is the only thing in your `each` loop, there is a shorthand for that:

```
!=partial('question', {collection:questions})
```

This will automatically render the partial once for each element in the `questions` array.

Comment: Isn't `!=partial('question', question);` a shorthand for `!=partial('question', { question: question });`?

Comment: No, if you just pass the `question` variable, jade does not know what you want to call the variable within the context of the partial.

Comment: Note: Jade no longer supports this method.